# How to end bot conversation and let real person handle responses in Dialog Flow?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, dialog-framework

I am developing a bot for business using Dialogflow. I want to keep an option "Talk to real person". When my customer wants to talk to real person, bot should stop and someone from my support staff will take care of that user.

How is it possible?
How can I pause/stop my bot and let real person handle conversation?

Comment: This is not possible on the Google Assistant and probably never will be possible.

Comment: @Bart I hope you got my point what I am trying to achieve. If that's not possible, can you suggest any alternative how can I bring in real person to handle messages?

Comment: The thing with Google Assistant is that it requires a response from your fullfilment in less than 5~ seconds. Even if you somehow found a way to fit an actual persons chatbox and use that as the fullfilment, it still wouldn't be possible. The Google Assistant simply wasn't designed to chat with other people, but with bots that have predefined or generated responses. Maybe you could make it work with just plain Dialogflow but I still doubt it.

Comment: @arsalan you could at some point of the conversation present a link to the user (if the surface is capable) to send it to another site where the user would chat with a real person.

Comment: Off topic but I'm going to up-vote simply because I'm amazed by the fact that this question has `1,000+` views, `0` up-votes and `0` down-votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While searching for answer, I send an email to Dialogflow support and got this reply next day.

> At this moment, you'll need to handle the task of passing conversations from bot to humans in your custom implementation. You can take a look at the following sample: https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs.

Hope this may help someone else having similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

By native google, Dialogflow doesn't support bot to human handoff or provide any Web interface to achieve this, but in dialogflow normally the action “input.unknown” used to hand off the conversation to a Human. The “input.unknown” action is built into Dialogflow and used with the default fallback intent. When none of the intents is matched, the default fallback intent is triggered and action associated with it is added in the response also you need to write a logic what bot should do after that.

But to make things easier you can integrate dialogflow with any third-party tool like [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/). As they provide pre-built chat widget user interface and bot to human handoff can be enabled on a click of a button, Please click [here](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/chatbot-human-handoff/) for more detailed information

PS: I work for Kommunicate

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related more to the external software that implements Dialogflow than Dialogflow itself.

You can use the PHP code of Support Board as a starting point, or you can use the Support Board software for that directly. It has the feature that asks the user if he/she wants to contact a human agent when the bot does not understand the question. If the user accepts the bot is automatically disabled and an email is sent to the agents.

More details at https://board.support/

PS: I work for Support Board